# incorrect log on parameters. asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Here is my code

```
 ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
                rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports/report.rpt"));
                rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

The second line throws me "[CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LogOnException] = {"\rError in File C:\Users\Prince\AppData\Local\Temp\report {1D0F4138-EB7B-4725-8B41-DCF38019B2C9}.rpt:\nUnable to connect: incorrect log on parameters."}" . Is anything i missed ...

Answer (score 0):

don't set Reports in your path

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
                rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("/report.rpt"));
                rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for that code . But Now i am getting "Unable to connect: incorrect log on parameters." I added a line rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("user","pass",".\\SQLEXPRESS","Admin"); . But even it's giving error

Comment: create a shared datasource in your ssrs report project (http://blog.infotoad.com/post/2009/07/02/Creating-a-Shared-Data-Source-in-Reporting-Services-2008.aspx) why? because you can access on shared datasource in SSRS Website ( http://yourservername/reports) and test your shared data source connection (test connection button).after, if it doesn't work  with a connection that works, it is your ssrs account service that doesn't have the right permission.http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/26/tutorials/4605/getting-started-with-ssrs-part-7-user-roles-and-permissions-in-ssrs-server